# Change settings of a running process

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, process, operating-system

I noticed that when a process starts for the first time, it statically reads some system parameter info only once and keeps it until terminated

which means,

that if there is some modification to the system parameters already read by the process, they wouldn'y reflect until the process is restarted.

e.g. Launch Notepad and type ';' key on the keyboard. Now change the input language from the langauge toolbar to Spanish. Now again hit the key ';'. Though the Input langauge has been changed to Spanish, the keys are still English (as seen by pressing ';' key).

Ideally on pressing ';' afer the input language is changed to Spanish, we should have noticed 'ñ'.

When we **restart** Notepad, we notice that ';' results in 'ñ' which means that the Notepad process needed to be restarted to take effect.

Is there some way where the process is not needed to be restarted to reflect the change in the Input method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If a process cares to, it can listen for notifications of changes to various system-wide settings. The [`wm_SettingChange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725497.aspx) message comes to mind.

It's a fool's errand to try to make some *other* process honor setting changes if it hasn't been written to do so. If a program isn't already listening for change notifications and acting upon them, you can't make it act differently.

Notepad probably isn't a good example; it's a pretty simple program, so it doesn't necessarily cover all the details that a good Windows program should.

The "answer" you gave, to refine your question, talks about changing the system's default input language with [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947.aspx). When you call that function, it will broadcast the `wm_SettingChange` message. To be notified of the change, other programs need to listen for that message; do that the same way you listen for any other window messages in your programming environment.

When you receive that message, the `wParam` parameter will be either `spi_GetDefaultInputLang` or `spi_SetDefaultInputLang`; I don't know which. That's you cue to call `SystemParametersInfo` to find out the new value of the setting. Based on what I've just read in ["Languages, Locales, and Keyboard Layouts"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646267.aspx#_win32_Languages_Locales_and_Keyboard_Layouts), you should call [`ActivateKeyboardLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646289.aspx) using the `HKL` value you get from `SystemParametersInfo`.

The process that changes the default input language cannot force other processes to use it. Until they choose for themselves to change their input languages, they will continue using whatever was the language when they started running. That's the distinction between the *default* setting and the *current* setting.

Comment: What Rob said. You can't make a program that was not designed to update when setting change start updating when settings change. That is a design choice the authors of Notepad decided not to code for.